# Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I have a class which has an init-method defined in xml

```
<bean id="appStarter" class="com.myapp.myClass" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy"/>
```

myClass:

```
public class myClass{

    private Thread t;

    public void init() {

             t = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true)
                        try {
                            doStuff();
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

            };
            t.start();
        }

public void destroy() {
        t.interrupt();
    }

}
```

When the app starts, these threads run fine, and everything works just fine
and after sometime i get the following exception.

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1273)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:755)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:569)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:531)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:510)
```

in the doStuff method:

```
public void doStuff(){

Session sessioned = Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties(),
                null);
        Store store = sessioned.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(hostName, userName, password);
.
.
.

}
```

I don't know why, any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe you can try to add some release function call (just link Singleton, connection Pool) in your destory event.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Problem solved after restarting the tomcat and apache, the tomcat was caching older version of the app.

Comment: How can I fix this permanently? What is the root cause for this issue? Because it is crashing my production application. I don't want to restart servers all the time... Need help.

Comment: Can second this, a restart of Tomcat made the problem go away.

Comment: This is likely a hotdeployment issue + already started threads, probably not own threads but from 3rd party libraries. [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41503819/1075524).

Comment: @JensKreidler: how do I know which 3rd party threads are causing the issue?

Comment: I've had a look into my application using the jvisualvm tool and investigated instances & threads

Comment: I had this problem this morning, it was caused by previous tasks who were causing other errors who prevented tomcat to restart successfully. In my case, inspecting log helped me. Worth cheking if there is huge processes (or zombie processes) still running, try ```ps aux``` it might create huge queues. And ofcourse after you find the source of problem, solve it first, then restart. After restart it should not appear. The best way to prevent these errors is to write smoke tests - it tests basically if machine can run with minimal resources.

Answer (score 22):

In short: this happens likely when you are hot-deploying webapps. 
For instance, your ide+development server hot-deploys a war again. Threads, that have been created previously are still running. But meanwhile their classloader/context is invalid and faces the IllegalAccessException / IllegalStateException becouse its orgininating webapp (the former runtime-environment) has been redeployed.

So, as states here, a restart does not permanently resolve this issue. Instead, it is better to find/implement a managed Thread Pool, s.th. like this to handle the termination of threads appropriately. In JavaEE you will use these ManagedThreadExeuctorServices. [A similar opinion and reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761644/1075524).

Examples for this are the EvictorThread of Apache Commons Pool, that "cleans" pooled instances according to the pool's configuration (max idle etc.).

Answer (score 8):

I suspect that this occurs after an attempt to undeploy your app. Do you ever [kill off that thread](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) that you've initialised during the `init()` process ? I would do this in the corresponding `destroy()` method.

Comment: right, it occurs after undeploying, and i don't kill of this thread, how to do that, please advise ?

Comment: ok after some search i made some changes to the code, but still get the same error, can you please see the changes in the code above ?

Comment: even when i used the interrupt in the destroy method, still get the same exception

Comment: Don't you need to handle the InterruptedException as per that link and bail out ?

Comment: even when handling it, the problem still there, i noticed that the cause is that the destroy method is not executed on app stop ? and also the thread still runs even when the application is stopped, this is very weird I don't know why ?

Comment: i also doubt that the problem may occur in this line Session.getDefaultInstance after i stopped the app and started it again ? i am very confused indeed

Comment: also the most weird that it runs locally with no problems but i get this exception when running the app online ?

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Your Server Can Resolve this problem.

I was getting the same error while Using Dynamic Jasper Reporting , When i deploy my Application for first use to Create Reports, the Report creation works fine, But Once I Do Hot Deployment of some code changes To the Server, I was getting This Error.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a local development tomcat launched from IDE, then restarting this IDE and rebuild project also helps.

Update:

You could also try to find if there is any running tomcat process in the background and kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error. My app ran fine inside of the eclipse development environment but when deployed to the production Tomcat server, the app would load fine, then when an endpoint was called, it generated the error:

> [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []

The error was caused because there were two different java versions. My development environment in eclipse was set to jdk-15 and the production server was running version 11.

To fix the issue, in eclipse, even when using jdk-15, I emulated java-11:

[image: eclipse > properties > java compiler]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. In my case I am using smart tomcat plugin in Intellij.
2. I was starting application without jars download.
3. Commented few lines in build.gralde which intellij suggest while gradle refresh.
4. Then jars got downloaded and application started.

Comment: Are you saying that you experienced a similar problem and are detailing how you solved it? Also, and pardon me, but my crystal ball is currently being repaired (and maybe the OP's is as well) so if you don't state which lines - in _build.gradle_ - you commented, I can't know. Are you saying that you just need to do a _gradle refresh_ and IntelliJ will tell you what to do?

Comment: yes . intellij will show error for those lines in build.gradle during gradle refresh. just comment them