# INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already

Tags: java, tomcat

i get this error

```
Mar 22, 2011 12:36:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
Mar 22, 2011 12:36:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.xmlparser.XmlParser.parseXmlFile(XmlParser.java:33)
    at com.xmlparser.XmlParser.<init>(XmlParser.java:25)
    at com.jobs.SendRoutineMessagesJob.execute(SendRoutineMessagesJob.java:29)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
```

could some one please guide me as to what mistake i am committing here. i am not sure if i would need to paste the source code as well.

Comment: I have the same problem that starts filling the logs, the server loops and does not serve requests. This happens when I try to reload something - xhtml files, class files...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems like i was creating instance of something which was already created..i removed the instance and now it works fine

Answer (score 12):

This because of you are deploying new instance of your application to server but the some thread or connection of previous instance attempts doing some business logic you have written. That's why, the main part of JVM called ClassLoader informs you about "Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already" and throws appropriate exception ... You can switch off auto deploy feature of Application Server which preferable on Production Environment and after deploying application restart server manually. Or you can in Class level control Servlet Life Cycle :))) during "pre deploy" close all connection or stop some threads. Or use sophisticated way controlling Threads with ManagedExecutorService. Good luck!!!

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Netbeans?  I had a similar error except it was could not load *oracle.sql.lnxlib*.  Like many posters have pointed out, this error usually has to do with Tomcat caching multiple instances of the application. A coworker was able to solve the problem for me by undeploying old instances of the application within Netbeans.  To do so, go to the **Services Tab > Servers** and then double click on **Apache Tomcat or TomEE** and after running the application once since opening netbeans,  a Web Applications Folder should appear.  If you double click on that, you should see instances of your application appear.  You should be able to right click them and then click undeploy (you may have to right click them and hit stop first).  Finally, you should stop and then start tomcat before building and running your application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use gradle there is an error

```
Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [].
```

The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
You can change `mysql-connect-java` to
`mysql: mysql-connector-java: 8.0.13`

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Tomcat on an Ubuntu server ....finally resolved it by doing a Tomcat shutdown with "systemctl stop tomcat" and then "sudo reboot" and then once the box came back up, starting Tomcat again