# INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load java.net.InetAddress

Tags: java

I'm experiencing this kind of exception, can someone help me about this problem?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker.getClientId(UpdateChecker.java:149)
at org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker.buildParamsString(UpdateChecker.java:120)
at org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker.buildUpdateCheckUrl(UpdateChecker.java:114)
at org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker.doCheck(UpdateChecker.java:55)
at org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(UpdateChecker.java:47)
at org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker.run(UpdateChecker.java:39)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm also getting the same exception with `Could not load java.net.URLEncoder` and `Could not load java.net.URLConnection`. I'm using Eclipse Indigo SR1 and Tomcat V6.0

Comment: what were you trying to execute ?

Comment: A web application, it's all working fine a while ago but when I'd try to run the server again (without modifying any codes), I receive this kind of exception without knowing why. I already tried to clean the project and restart the server, even shut down my PC but still my app doesn't running.

Comment: I have explained here why this happens, may be this information will helpful too  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386934/web-instance-already-stopped/38761644#38761644

Comment: I have answered this question below, please have a look, the solution doesn't require any kind of restarts

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can solve this problem  after restarting the server, the server iscaching older version of the app.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386934/web-instance-already-stopped)

Comment: Everything's fine now. I've just restarted the server, and for the nth time, it finally works. Thanks @PSR.

Comment: I was not able to fix this even after restarting. I finally found that there was a dll (.SO for linux) which was needed by one one of my library jars to compile . This was missing. I added that .so in my tomcat library and restarted tomcat. Fixed. I still have to figure out why this exception though.

Comment: This is not a solution. This error also comes up when starting Tomcat within a fresh Docker container on a brand new VM.

Comment: @mjj1409 how is that link you shared here helpful to the OP reported problem ?? I don't see any connection

Answer (score 24):

You cannot resolve this problem by "restarting the server".

The problem is that when you update your app by uploading a new version to Tomcat, some resource is not cleaned up properly. Could be anything from a runaway thread, to some kind of scheduled service, to a listener. When that process tries to load a class, Tomcat will detect and prevent it.

The solution to the problem is to properly keep track of, and on shutdown close, those threads.

Answer (score 2):

I have also experienced this problem recently.
In my case the problem was generated by an unhandled exception in `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` which was logged in one localhost-date.log.
Because of that exception the webapp was not deployed, but an already started `java.util.concurrent.Executors` was still running which caused another chain of exceptions in catalina-date.log:
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load WhatEver.class*.

The solution for my case:

- check all the Tomcat logs
- fix exceptions in `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue. I have solved by increasing the permsize of Server in the VM arguments `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Answer (score 0):

Lately, we faced a similar issue. Our Server Solution had 4 Web Applications all utilizing BouncyCastle-related APIs. Every Web Application is responsible for performing the required task using BouncyCastle APIs. The WebApps were running on Apache Tomcat 10.1

The issue started happening when we reloaded the WebApp to verify the integrity even when 1 Web App was unavailable for some time.

The problem was resolved by following these 2 steps:

1. BouncyCastle was added as one of the Providers when the Web Application was started, which is a one time activity.

> Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

2. BouncyCastle Provider was supplied to every API that had the support of providing one explicitly, such as the below one. This is the most important part of it, as without this, the IllegalStateException or "Application stopped" issue was consistently happening.

> KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", new
> BouncyCastleProvider());

When the above 2 steps were performed in every API and every WebApp the BouncyCastle related issues completely disappeared.