# Spring boot ResourceUtils.getURL Illegal access: this web application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring boot ResourceUtils.getURL

print exception

```
Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens likely when you are hot-deploying webapps.

Just restarting the server will solve this problem.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521270/info-illegal-access-this-web-application-instance-has-been-stopped-already-co) for reference

Comment: request -> controller(processing) -> request (close connection) ->  controller(processing  invoke ResourceUtils.getURL ) ->  thrown exception(Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already)

 [[[[[[[ Is that the same reason? ]]]]]]

Comment: Yes..it might be a reason...just try the solution