# Intellj Maven project failling to start "Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details."

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, tomcat5.5

I'm running Catalina 8.5.51 on IntelliJ and everything is configured properly when I hit the run button the following stack trace is thrown and server won't start:

It's pointing that I need to see the logs here, are these the calalina logs? "See server log for details."

As a side note: My artifact is already selected on the server setting. What else could I be missing?

```
    /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/bin/catalina.sh run
    [2020-02-26 06:16:47,616] Artifact -ws:war: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.081 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 5 2020 22:26:25 UTC
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.51.0
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.14.5
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_242-b08
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            AdoptOpenJDK
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/ibraheemfauzi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_shipperhq-ws
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/ibraheemfauzi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_shipperhq-ws/conf/logging.properties
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx4096m
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/Users/ibraheemfauzi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_shipperhq-ws/jmxremote.password
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/Users/ibraheemfauzi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_shipperhq-ws/jmxremote.access
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/ibraheemfauzi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_shipperhq-ws
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/temp
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/ibraheemfauzi/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.133 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.147 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.154 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 248 ms
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.170 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.170 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.175 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:53.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 25 ms
    Connected to server
    [2020-02-26 06:16:53,692] Artifact shipperhq-ws:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    26-Feb-2020 18:16:58.147 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.181 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/docs]
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.256 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/docs] has finished in [75] ms
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.257 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/manager]
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.310 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.313 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/manager] has finished in [56] ms
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.313 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/examples]
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.457 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.467 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/examples] has finished in [154] ms
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.467 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/ROOT]
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.527 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.528 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [61] ms
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.528 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/host-manager]
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.578 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:03.579 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [51] ms
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:15.490 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:15.492 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/shipperhq-ws] startup failed due to previous errors
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:15.521 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [shipperhq-ws] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2d6badeb]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventTranslator] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventTranslator@7c3bd069]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:15.521 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [shipperhq-ws] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@62e36e5d]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl@cff2a40b[appender=ShipperWsError, appenderName=ShipperWsError, level=null, intLevel=2147483647, recursive=java.lang.ThreadLocal@62e36e5d, filter=null]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:15.522 INFO [Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@4f2c28ee]-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.FileExtension$2]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.FileExtension$2]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1378)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1366)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1218)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.<init>(RollingFileManager.java:142)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:645)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:608)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:116)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:188)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:145)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:61)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:958)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:898)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.createAppender(RoutingAppender.java:271)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.getControl(RoutingAppender.java:255)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.append(RoutingAppender.java:225)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:79)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.actualAsyncLog(AsyncLogger.java:381)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.execute(RingBufferLogEvent.java:160)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:45)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:29)
            at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.processEvents(BatchEventProcessor.java:168)
            at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:125)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    AsyncLogger error handling event seq=0, value='[ERROR calling class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.toString(): java.lang.NullPointerException]':
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/FileExtension$2
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.<init>(RollingFileManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:645)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:608)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:116)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:188)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:145)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:61)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:958)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:898)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.createAppender(RoutingAppender.java:271)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.getControl(RoutingAppender.java:255)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.append(RoutingAppender.java:225)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:79)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.actualAsyncLog(AsyncLogger.java:381)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.execute(RingBufferLogEvent.java:160)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:29)
        at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.processEvents(BatchEventProcessor.java:168)
        at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:125)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.FileExtension$2]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1368)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1218)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.FileExtension$2]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1378)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1366)
        ... 31 more
    [2020-02-26 06:17:15,534] Artifact -ws:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
    26-Feb-2020 18:17:20.523 INFO [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1378)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1030)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:63)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.51/bin/catalina.sh stop
    26-Feb-2020 23:08:49.431 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
    26-Feb-2020 23:08:49.433 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    26-Feb-2020 23:08:49.450 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
    26-Feb-2020 23:08:49.482 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    26-Feb-2020 23:08:49.485 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Disconnected from server
```

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15521361/2960034

Comment: That's not the same thing actually. Thanks though!

Comment: how do you bundle your dependencies. For ex: how did you mentioned the log4j dependency in your pom. Error is you do not have the log4j class FileExtension in your CP

Comment: @ChiranK.I'm using Maven to build the dependencies - not sure if this answers your question.