# Spring continuously throws same error just after first 500 error

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, netbeans-8

Can any one explain.

I am using Netbeans and working on spring boot MVC + thymeleaf + mongodb.

As I modified some code and save, Netbeans auto compiles the code and then the refresh the browser to see the changes. Everything almost working fine but during my rapid modification and multiple saves, Sometime i leave syntax error or any thing netbeans again auto compile and when i refresh browser it sale 500 error but i am okay with that i fix my error than save again netbeans compiles I refresh page then everything is working fine. but the strange thing is on the netbeans console it keeps populating netbeans output window with below error stack trace every 2 seconds.

that only happens after first 500 error.

```
 25-Jun-2018 01:14:41.407 INFO [cluster-ClusterId{value='5b2ffb579a044517f5820132', description='null'}-localhost:27017] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.connection.ServerDescription]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.connection.ServerDescription]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1283)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.loadClass(PackagingDataCalculator.java:204)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.bestEffortLoadClass(PackagingDataCalculator.java:228)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.computeBySTEP(PackagingDataCalculator.java:135)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.populateUncommonFrames(PackagingDataCalculator.java:111)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.populateFrames(PackagingDataCalculator.java:104)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.calculate(PackagingDataCalculator.java:58)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.calculatePackagingData(ThrowableProxy.java:142)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:122)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.warn(Logger.java:692)
 at com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger.warn(SLF4JLogger.java:91)
 at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be that the server seems to be caching an old version of the application you're developing.

Could be related to the auto-compile and deploy feature you have turned on for NetBeans.

Have a look here for more: [web instance already stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386934/web-instance-already-stopped)

Comment: I have also undeploye the project but error still there until i restart server