# Could not load [org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.GOST3411$Mappings]

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8, bouncycastle

I am using tomcat8 Server, .bouncycastle for Document signature. 
one war file already running on my server. when i have deployed new war file for my second project then Getting below exception.

I have hit and trial every link on stackoverflow but not luck

> org.apache.**catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading
>   Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped**
>   already. Could not load
>   [org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.GOST3411$Mappings]. The
>   following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to
>   attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access. 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application
>   instance has been stopped already. Could not load

```
 public static void xmlSigner(File xmlFile,String pfxFilePath){
    try{
            File pfxFile=new File(pfxFilePath);
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            log.info("Above key store ");
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "BC");
            log.info("below key store ");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(pfxFile),password.toCharArray());
            log.info("load pfx file key store ");
            String alias = (String) keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
            Certificate[] certificateChain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
            X509Certificate publickeyCertificate = (X509Certificate) certificateChain[certificateChain.length - 1];
            //log.info("privateKey : " + privateKey);
            //log.info("xmlSigner : " + xmlFile);
            log.info("SignerClient - Above Sign and Zip");
            SignerUtil.signAndzipFile(xmlFile, privateKey, publickeyCertificate);
            log.info("Successfully Signed");
        }
        catch(Exception xmlSignerException){
            log.error("xmlSigner : ", xmlSignerException);
            xmlSignerException.printStackTrace();

        }

   }
```

i am getting exception on below line

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "BC");
```

Comment: Maybe those links can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386934/web-instance-already-stopped , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521270/info-illegal-access-this-web-application-instance-has-been-stopped-already-co

Comment: @AbdouRayes : okay

Comment: @AbdouRayes : not getting expected answer, I already tried all the given answer

Comment: Lot of answer regarding server restart issue has been resolved. Actually i'm working on pre production  environment. So i want to fixed on my current environment because of i do not have access to restart the production environment.

Comment: The most common cause of class loading issues with BouncyCastle classes is having more than one copy of the BC jar(s) in the classpath, often different versions. Please check for that. Also please mention the version of BC you are using, which specific BC jars you are using, and where those jars are located.

Comment: @PeterDettman I will update you tomorrow regarding version of bc and location of jars file, actually I leave my office today

Comment: @PeterDettman : in 1st war file i am using bouncycastle <version>1.56</version> and in 2nd war file i am using bouncycastle <version>1.55</version>, I have made change version of bouncycastle <version>1.56</version> in both project. Then it seems working fine, even both project(war) running on same tomcat . Thank you for your reply. you save my life (* _ *)

Answer (score 3):

I have face the same issue, Tomcat restart has resolved the issue.

```java
keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
// java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS12 not found
```

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyStore (provider: BC) cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1649)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1592)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:698)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:896)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi$BCPKCS12KeyStore]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1354)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1211)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1172)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1636)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi$BCPKCS12KeyStore]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and answer 

Comment: Restarting a server cannot be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please first check that org.bouncycastle has many versions. Keep one version, and if use tomcat, restart tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Lately, we faced a similar issue. Our Server Solution had 4 Web Applications all utilizing BouncyCastle-related APIs. Every Web Application is responsible for performing the required task using BouncyCastle APIs. The WebApps were running on Apache Tomcat 10.1

The issue started happening when we reloaded the WebApp to verify the integrity even when 1 Web App was unavailable for some time.

The problem was resolved by following these 2 steps:

1. BouncyCastle was added as one of the Providers when the Web Application was started, which is a one time activity.

   Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
2. BouncyCastle Provider was supplied to every API that had the support of providing one explicitly, such as the below one. This is the most important part of it, as without this, the IllegalStateException or "Application stopped" issue was consistently happening.

   KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", new BouncyCastleProvider());

When the above 2 steps were performed in every API and every WebApp the BouncyCastle related issues completely disappeared.