# apache tomcat illegal access

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm getting the same "Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already" but the solution is not working for me.

[INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load java.net.InetAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521270/info-illegal-access-this-web-application-instance-has-been-stopped-already-co)

[Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945153/illegal-access-this-web-application-instance-has-been-stopped-already)

It seems like the error has to do with old cache or another instance. I'm on a mac running apache 7.0.61. I tried the following but none worked:

1. restarting with "bash startup.sh" and "bash shutdown.sh"
2. clearing the work directory
3. redownloading apache tomcat and starting with a fresh version
4. redepolying .war file
5. restarting my laptop

What am I missing?

Comment: I think step#3 & #5 is not required. Can you paste the relevant stack trace ?