# Spring hibernate mysql Date mismatch

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, date

In my POJO I have field:

```
@Column(name="batch_creation_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date batchCreationDate;
```

In mySQL DB the cresponding column is a `DATE` type.
In java project, the `mysql.properties` has `jdbc.url` with this parameter `serverTimezone=UTC`.

In jsp page, I have form to enter date in format stadet above.

The problem is, when I enter ie. `06-07-2018` and send the form, on the page I can see `05-07-2018`

On google I've found the solution, to setup project time zone to UTC like this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

But this solution give me errors during starting up tomcat (I've spent hours to get rid of this error):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [].
```

so I don't find this out as a good way to solve this problem.

Could you help me to resolve this issue, and on jsp page get the exact date?

Comment: Hope this will help you.                                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521270/info-illegal-access-this-web-application-instance-has-been-stopped-already-co                                                                                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945153/illegal-access-this-web-application-instance-has-been-stopped-already/4956031

Comment: I've tried all of ideas from this site before and error is still occuring (but the DATE is correct)

Comment: You should use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` instead of `Date`. It solves a ton of issues. A Date object is basically a TimeStamp (or Instant) with an offset to your current TimeZone.

Comment: After hours of struggling, I've set up `serverTimezone=Europe/Warsaw` and it works for now. After reading some documentation, `LocalDate` is also a good choice - thanks for the hint.